# Can no longer run mongod command to start after typing "sudo pkill -f mongod"

Tags: database, mongodb

The "mongod" command had been working fine for the past few days until I typed the command "sudo pkill -f mongod" in my terminal. Here is the result after I issue "mongod".

> ```
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.543-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically
> disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
> --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",  
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":718,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Georges-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.546-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.548-04:00"},"s":"E", 
> "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException
> in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data
> directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify
> another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by
> adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.548-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown:
> going to close listening sockets"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.548-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",     
> "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow
> Control ticket acquisitions."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.548-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-16T13:32:49.548-04:00"},"s":"I", 
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
> ```

I have found a temporary solution which is by typing "mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb". How can I undo this so that I can start the db connection by issuing "mongod"?

edit: included terminal output

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 2):

If your O.S is OS X and mongodb is installed via Homebrew try:

```sh
brew services restart mongodb-community 
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Comment: you dont need to start mongodb-community when you restart it

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem I solved Please try

1. Data directory C:\data\db\
2. Run administrator command prompt
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data\

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder in C drive named data and inside data make db folder and rerun the command it will work.

Comment: This is suggesting the same thing as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below commands. If still not work, try after restart your pc.

```
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod stop
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your current directory. If you are not in your root,

```
cd ~
```

use this command to get to the root and now run the `mongod` command.